# Delphi - records with variant parts

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, record

I want to have a record (structure) with a 'polymorphic' comportment. It will have several fields used in all the cases, and I want to use other fields only when I need them. I know that I can accomplish this by variant parts declared in records. I don't know if it is possible that at design time I can access only the elements I need. To be more specific, look at the example bellow

```
program consapp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ExceptionLog,
  SysUtils;

type
  a = record
   b : integer;
   case isEnabled : boolean of
    true : (c:Integer);
    false : (d:String[50]);
  end;


var test:a;

begin
 test.b:=1;
 test.isEnabled := False;
 test.c := 3; //because isenabled is false, I want that the c element to be unavailable to the coder, and to access only the d element. 
 Writeln(test.c);
 readln;
end.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All variant fields in a variant record are accessible at all times, irrespective of the value of the tag.

In order to achieve the accessibility control you are looking for you would need to use properties and have runtime checks to control accessibility.

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
  strict private
    FIsEnabled: Boolean;
    FInt: Integer;
    FStr: string;
    // ... declare the property getters and settings here
  public
    property IsEnabled: Boolean read FIsEnabled write FIsEnabled;
    property Int: Integer read GetInt write SetInt;
    property Str: string read GetString write SetString;
  end;
...
function TMyRecord.GetInt: Integer;
begin
  if IsEnabled then
    Result := FInt
  else
    raise EValueNotAvailable.Create('blah blah');
end;
```

Comment: This is perfectly correct, but in this case, I'd rather use a class instead of a record. It will allow adding the inheritance feature, which makes sense here (e.g. the IsEnable property is typically to be handled at a parent level, and shared among children).

Answer (score 4):

Even if I heard that by original Niklaus Wirth's Pascal definition all should work as you expected, I saw no such behaviour in Delphi, starting from its ancestor, [Turbo Pascal 2.0](http://primepuzzle.com/tp2/turbo-pascal-2.0-manual-11.txt). Quick look at FreePascal showed that [its behaviour](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu16.html) is the same. As said in [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records):

> You can read or write to any field of any variant at any time; but if you write to a field in one variant and then to a field in another variant, you may be overwriting your own data. The tag, if there is one, functions as an extra field (of type ordinalType) in the non-variant part of the record."

Regarding your intent, as far as I understood it, I would use two different classes, kind of

```
    a = class
      b : Integer
    end;

    aEnabled = class(a)
      c: Integer
    end;

    aDisabled = class(a)
      d: String //plus this way you can use long strings
    end;
```

This way you can get some support from IDE's Code Editor even at designtime. More useful, though, is that it will be *much* more easier to modify and support later.

However, if you need quick switching of record variable values at runtime, [@David Heffernan's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901805/delphi-records-with-variant-parts/7901909#7901909) , to use properties and have runtime checks, is more reasonable.

Answer (score -3):

The example given is NOT a variant record, it includes  all the fields all the time.

A true variant record has the variants sharing the same memory.  You just use the "case discriminator: DiscType of ..... " syntax, no need for a separate field telling you what variant is active.

Comment: It is a variant record. The case makes it so.

Comment: You're talking about **absolute** variables, which is another completely different thing. David is right, this ia a variant record.

Comment: It does not includes all the fields, it instead gives access to all parts after `case` _at the same time_, and all of them share the same memory. So it's similar to **absolute** vars, except: it is more structured; you have tag variable; and, possible, memory alignment is a bit different